# how to convert float to integer or text - google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

The following function returns a float number (.0)
how can i convert it to integer, or text?
Thanks!

```
function test(){
  const url = "https://www.7timer.info/bin/astro.php?lon=113.2&lat=23.1&ac=0&unit=metric&output=json&tzshift=0";
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  const data = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
  var cloud = data.dataseries[0].cloudcover;
  Logger.log(cloud); //result is 9.0
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const cloud = 9.0
console.log(cloud.toFixed(0))
console.log(cloud.toString())
console.log(String(cloud))
```

You can use `cloud.toFixed(0)` for removing that decimal.

You can use `cloud.toString()` or in ES6 `String(cloud)`

**Reference:-**

[toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

[toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)